# In Slack, how to find conversations (threads) that involve two specific persons

Tags: slack

I can use `from:@Some Person` and `to:@Some Person` in Slack search but that doesn't find plain mentions, or just interactions between two people when they don't necessarily tag each other.

My use case is that I've been involved in a discussion (thread in some channel) with another person from the company but can't remember any keywords that would return search results. I'd like to construct a search query like this:

```
involves:@Borek Bernard involves:@Other Person
```

But Slack doesn't support the `involves` keyword (like e.g. GitHub does).

I have tried two "from:" operators but get zero results as well:

```
(doesn't work either)

from:@Borek Bernard from:@Other Person
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like they've added a feature to search using "**with**" so you can search for "**with**:@personA **with**:@personB".

See https://slack.com/help/articles/202528808-Search-in-Slack for more details.

Comment: That is great news and seems to work, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I've had a conversion with support and they confirmed that it's not possible (as of June 2021).

**UPDATE Nov 2021**: It's now possible, see [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/160330/6479).

Comment: you may now be able to accept your own answer

Comment: Wondering if "not possible" is a typo. Did you mean "it's _now_ possible"?

Comment: @stone Yes, you're right, I've updated the text .